# Working Directory for local github actions in subdirectory

Tags: github-actions, building-github-actions

I'm trying to keep multiple github actions in the same monorepo using subdirectories, and run them like:

workflow.yml

```
// [...]
jobs:
  run_my_script:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out current repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: ./my_action2
        with:
          my_input_var: "david"
```

./my_action2/action.yml

```
// [...]
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    # Checkout files in this repo
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v1

    - name: Run myscript
      run: python myscript.py "${{ inputs.my_input_var }}" # location: ./my_action2/myscript.py
      shell: bash
```

The problem I'm having is that my action uses a python script in it's subdirectory, but the `uses:` action appears to run from the GITHUB_WORKING_DIR of the workflow and not the directory of the action itself.

```
python: can't open file 'myscript.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I've looked through most of the working-directory questions surrounding github actions, but I'm still stumped.

I've also tried adding `working-directory: ./my_action2` to the job's `defaults:` but it looks like it's not propagating to `run:` commands within the `uses:` step.

My workaround in the meantime has been to add an input for `myaction2_working_directory` in the workflow, and then add `working-directory: ${{ inputs.myaction2_working_directory }}` to every `run:` command in the action. This seems inelegant and repetitive. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

contrary to the answer by Grzegorz, you cannot just `run: cd foo` and then expect all following steps to have a working directory of `foo`.  as far as i can tell, the only way to do this is with the "workaround" the OP already posted -- add an input named e.g. `working-directory` to your action and then add `working-directory: ${{ inputs.working-directory }}` to every step.  see https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#runsstepsworking-directory

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem and for my composite actions I just added a first step as:

`run: cd  ${{ inputs.working_directory }}`

and then all next steps are running in it.
I couldn't find a better way and having `working-directory` copy pasted was also something I didn't like.

Comment: Thank you - this helps a lot - I wasn't aware that the location would remain between multiple steps after changing directory.  I'll give it a shot and mark as correct